# Start a program, that is started by another program, through powershell (core), is that possible?

Tags: powershell

what I want to achieve is this (just a simplified example):

If i start "pwsh ping.exe" I can 'intercept' ping by putting in my profile.ps1 something like:

function ping.exe {Write-Host 'This is my custom ping'}

and that gets printed instead of starting the system`s ping.exe.

But now i have this little program,let`s say, call_ping.exe(simplified):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int __cdecl wmain( int argc, WCHAR *argv[] )
{
    
    STARTUPINFOW si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
 
    WCHAR pingW[] = L"c:\\windows\\system32\\ping.exe";

    memset( &si, 0, sizeof( STARTUPINFO )); si.cb = sizeof( STARTUPINFO ); memset( &pi, 0, sizeof( PROCESS_INFORMATION ) );
    CreateProcessW( pingW, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi );
 
    return 0; 

}
```

Then if I run 'pwsh call_ping.exe' the system's ping get's called instead of my function. Is there a way to get around this/solution within powershell (core) or am I asking the impossible?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Don't define `function ping.exe`, and problem is solved. That's not [what you are after](https://xyproblem.info/), is it?

Comment: No, you`re right. I try to achieve that i can "write" my own 'ping' in profile.ps1. So if the program  (it's a game) starts ping.exe i can feed it whatever I want, by adjusting the function 'ping.exe' in profile.ps1. Note: It's not intended for cheating, it` a simple game, not commercial or so

Comment: Unless it launches ping via absolute path,change the environment for the game so that it finds your version of ping before Windows'.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but that cannot work, can it? It`s not a real program, but a function/script in my profile.ps1 so environment won`t affect that (?)